# How to get a date selector when using the DocuSign API to add a date tab dynamically?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create a Date using the DocuSign API where it mimics the Text field with Validation set to Date and then one of the three support "Validation date mask".  When I submit the api request using the ValidationPattern of "^[0-9]{4}/((|0)[1-9]|1[0-2])/((|0)[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$"...it does not give me the calendar selector like the when I drag a date in the form editor.

```
Date date = new Date();

date.DocumentId = "1";
date.PageNumber = "1";
date.RecipientId = "1";
date.XPosition = "100";
date.YPosition = "100";
date.TabLabel = "txtbx_code_date_yyyymmdd";
date.ValidationPattern = "^(|by DocuSign)[0-9]{4}\\/((|0)[1-9]|1[0-2])\\/((|0)[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$";
date.ValidationMessage = "YYYY/MM/DD";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
jlimited.

Answer (score 0):

The Date tab is also know as "Date Signed" and is auto-populated with the date when the recipient/signer signs the document, you cannot make it editable to the user.
You can use a text tab with your validation pattern for your needs instead.

Comment: Changing it to a text field worked for the Validation.  But how do I get the calendar selector to display?

Comment: There's no calendar selector in DocuSign signing that I've seen. Might be a feature request.